# Laptop battery life decreased compared to Windows 7

Tags: drivers, partitioning, battery

I'm new to linux and few days ago i installed it on my laptop. I have windows 7 64-bit in one partition and on other partitions the ubuntu 12.10(6gb), swap partition(8gb) and /home partition about 60gb. The battery life on windows have about 3 hr life but on ubuntu only 1hr and 20 min. what might be problem?

As i say before i new to linux and it's my 1-st time i'm using it. also in the system on ubuntu it says that the graphic is unknown, but when i'm checking it through package that i installed it recognize my graphic card.
Maybe there is a problem with the drivers of the card?

I'm using dell vostro 3450, i have 2 graphic cards AMD Radeon HD 6630M and Intel graphic card on the mother board. From what i read on the forums it might be a problem with the drivers when there are 2 graphic cards.

I have 3 questions, the first is about the battery life, the second one is about the graphic cards drivers and the third about the size of the partitions(i set those size's from what i read on the forums).

Thanks a lot for the help.